# MasterPage Container Control Id's

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings,

I created a aspx page that uses a master page. Inside I have a control, let's say txtName and I have a submit button, that when I press it it will submit the text in the txtName to another page.

The problem is that the Request.Form key does not have the txtName, instead it something like clt00$Container0&txtName.

Isn't there a way to easily find the key that I want to retrieve from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the behaviour via [Cross Page Postback](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/cross-page-posting-in-aspnet.html). Then you can access the value via `PreviousPage.FindControl("txtName")` or via a custom property (see section "Using Property to expose and Consume values of TextBox" in the linked article above)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they r with in the same form when, it 
renders onthe client. If not u will not get on server
look view source n see where u master page control
is